# .net remoting ,client server,remote callback

Tags: c#-4.0, callback, .net-remoting

i have created a server and a client ( .net , remoting ,c sharp). Server is a singleton server(not neccesary i guess). And then i am calling a asynchronous method which is located in the server remotely,after execute server sends reply using the  Asyncstate object which i have sent to the server when i was calling the function as a parameter(Remote Callback). All works fine. but if server crashed while executing the method ,there is no way to notify the client.how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familar with the particular tools you are using, but if the server is unable to respond to the client for some reason, the client's connection should be able to report a timeout. If the client experiences a timeout, you can take this as indication that the server has crashed, or otherwise failed, and do something at the clientside as neccesary.

Comment: when i am calling the remote ,i am only passing the object,then server put the results in to the object and server calls client again (remote callback).